# SQL Query fails with no error message

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter 3 and I'm trying to change a SQL Query from

> SELECT id, shelfmark from documents  where collection_id='ubb'

to

> SELECT document_id, shelfmark from documents_revisions
>        where collection_id='ubb' and latest='1'

The first SQL Query is generated with:

```
 public function getDocumentsForCollection($sCollectionId) {
    $this->db->select('id, shelfmark');
    $this->db->where('collection_id', $sCollectionId);
    $query = $this->db->get('documents');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $query->result();
    }
    else {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

In order to match the second SQL Query I updated this method to

```
  public function getDocumentsForCollection($sCollectionId) {
    $this->db->select('document_id, shelfmark');
    $where = "collection_id=" . $sCollectionId . " AND latest=1";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get('documents_revisions');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $query->result();
    }
    else {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

When I open the page where the function is executed I just see a blank page.

How can I debug in CodeIgniter to see the generated SQL query of my PHP function?

What's wrong with my updated PHP function?

---

I updated the method to:

```
  public function getDocumentsForCollection($sCollectionId) {
    $this->db->select('document_id, shelfmark');
    $where = array("collection_id"=>$sCollectionId,"latest"=>1);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get('documents_revisions');
    var_dump($query); exit;
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $query->result();
    }
    else {
      return 'foo';
    }
  }
```

With var_dump($query) right before the if conditional I get:

> object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)#65 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> object(mysqli)#16
>   (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(160) ["client_info"]=> string(79)
>   "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id:
>   b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $" ["client_version"]=>
>   int(50012) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL
>   ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0)
>   { } ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via
>   UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=>
>   string(23) "5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1" ["server_version"]=> int(50718)
>   ["stat"]=> string(139) "Uptime: 252001 Threads: 3 Questions: 36434
>   Slow queries: 0 Opens: 501 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 313 Queries
>   per second avg: 0.144" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000"
>   ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(2507)
>   ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } ["result_id"]=> object(mysqli_result)#38
>   (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2)
>   ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(160) ["type"]=> int(0) }
>   ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0)
>   ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["row_data"]=> NULL }

The affected_rows represents the amount of documents I get if I run the SQL query directly in MySQL: ["affected_rows"]=> int(160)

Comment: try var_dump($query) before the if statement. Also, verify that you show all errors (e.g. E_ALL) in php.ini under error reporting

Comment: You can have multiple `where` and they will be used as `AND`. Check the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data).

Comment: You can use `$this->db->where('collection_id', $sCollectionId); $this->db->where('latest', 1);`

Comment: @Glubus I tried but I'm getting no output for var_dump instead getting a Server Error 500.

Comment: @StandardNerd whats inside `$sCollectionId`

Comment: a string like "ubb"

Comment: r u sure data exist for current SQL ??

Comment: yes. Maybe it has something to do with the MySQL flush tables...

Comment: what no way there is such a issue in CI

Answer (score 1):

You must pass an array in case of multiple conditions in db->where() clause

```
$where = array("collection_id"=>$sCollectionId,"latest"=>1);
```

FULL CODE:

```
public function getDocumentsForCollection($sCollectionId) {
$this->db->select('document_id, shelfmark');
$where = array("collection_id"=>$sCollectionId,"latest"=>1);
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get('documents_revisions');
if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
  return $query->result();
}
else {
  return 'foo';
}
```

}

will generate the result as follows:

```
SELECT `document_id`, `shelfmark` FROM (`documents_revisions`) WHERE `collection_id` = 'ubb' AND `latest` = 1
```

Using Where Clause Complete Guide: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: I get "A PHP Error was encountered - 
Severity: Notice -
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$id"

Comment: Not just an array, since you can call `where` multiple times, as said mentioned in the comments of the question.

Comment: @FirstOne Yes, we can call where clause multiple times and also pass an array of multiple conditions within 1 clause. It depends on our own coding style :)
Complete Guide: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: @StandardNerd, Please use the full code as this:

`public function getDocumentsForCollection($sCollectionId) {
    $this->db->select('document_id, shelfmark');
    $where = array("collection_id"=>$sCollectionId,"latest"=>1);
 $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get('documents_revisions');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $query->result();
    }
    else {
      return 'foo';
    }
  }`